# HTTP ERROR: 503 Sonar 3.5

Tags: sonarqube

After starting sonar, i get this error in browser:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
  Powered by Jetty://
```

sonar log :

STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/18 15:54:12 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/18 15:54:13 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:13 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:13 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:13 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:13 | 2014-06-18 15:54:13.505:INFO::Logging to org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger@c2ff5 via org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:13 | 2014-06-18 15:54:13.591:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:13 | 2014-06-18 15:54:13.856:INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2014.06.18 15:54:14 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  Sonar Server / 3.5 / b1603798909f471cb4e40841c5c4cb39b2728b47
2014.06.18 15:54:14 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
2014.06.18 15:54:16 ERROR o.s.s.p.Platform  Database relates to a more recent version of sonar. Please check your settings.
org.sonar.core.persistence.BadDatabaseVersion: Database relates to a more recent version of sonar. Please check your settings.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:16 | 2014-06-18 15:54:16.749:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@d5276a{/,file:/opt/sonar-3.5/war/sonar-server}
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:16 | org.sonar.core.persistence.BadDatabaseVersion: Database relates to a more recent version of sonar. Please check your settings.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/18 15:54:16 | 2014-06-18 15:54:16.768:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000
(END)

Thank you,
Mihai

Comment: do you have corresponding code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear : "Database relates to a more recent version of sonar". You're for instance trying to make Sonar 3.5 using a DB already in version 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

resolved. there ware multiple Sonar version, i started 4.1 and is woring.